# couldn't format partition in SSD

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-8, ssd, amd-radeon

so.. I get the stupid error when I format my `SSD`. when I try to install `Windows 7/8/8.1` I get this error:

`Windows couldn't format a partition on disk 0. The error occured while preparing the partition selected for installation.  Error code 0x80070057`

when searched out the forums, blogs and etc. but my problem not solved. The 'same' error with other OS installation (for example: Ubuntu, Linux)

I bought SSD 2 months ago. My SSD model is: `AMD Radeon R7 Series 480GB 2.5-Inch SATA III`

please help me.

Big thanks
Best,
Mirjalal